# Django CMS only one entry in model

Tags: django-models, django-cms

I want to make a persistent floating(using CSS) contact button on every page in Django CMS.

I need to get the first item in DB and construct the URL according to it in the template.

Also, the place holder should display first item and allow editing it everywhere if possible.

Or maybe not have an input at all and allow editing the contact info in the admin.

Or have an option to use the first one which is default or a different number for a particular page.

I have currently made my plugin but it creates a new entry every time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to appear on every page you need to make use of `static_placeholder` [(docs)](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/introduction/templates_placeholders.html#static-placeholders) which acts like a normal placeholder but you only need to add plugins to it on one page for them to appear in every page which you include the `static_placeholder` of the same name.

For example I often have a footer which includes a menu & allows a client to add their own content like contact address, phone number etc. The easiest example of how you could do this would be to include the following template tag in your `base.html` so that it gets included in all pages inheriting your base template.

```
{% static_placeholder "footer" site %}
```

Also the standard `placeholder` tag doesn't work in apps, so if you include apps in your CMS site via app hooks you can also include the `static_placeholder` in the app templates to add plugins.